# Add internal border on div within the padding

Tags: css, border, padding

I have a div with a padding and I would like to add an "internal" border, considering padding. For example, consider to have this CSS:

```
div#border {
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

My goal in this case is to create an internal solid border, far 10px from div border, but I only get an external border ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/przcag67/1/)). Adding an internal div does the trick but adds an extra HTML element ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udbkaf8j/2/)):

```
div#border {
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}

div#internal {
    border:1px solid;
}
```

I've tried to add an outline as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710360/padding-on-div-border), but when I have two adiacent divs with outline, there's an overlap between ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kd8cfn1u/)).

Is there a pure-CSS solution to add an "internal" border to a div, considering padding, without adding extra HTML elements and without overlapping on adiacent divs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution #1 Use box-shadow with inset

We can take advantage of the fact that multiple values can be used for the box-shadow property.

The trick here is to set the first inner shadow with the background color of the div, and the second inner shadow - which is slightly larger - with the color of the border.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/przcag67/5/)**

```css
div#border {
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 9px #ccc, inset 0 0 0 10px black;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="border">some content</div>
```

### Solution #2 Use outline with the `outline-offset` property.

```
outline:1px solid;
outline-offset: -10px;
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/przcag67/4/)**

```css
div#border {
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid;
  outline-offset: -10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="border">some content</div>
```

Comment: Correct! With the constraint to have padding equal to outline-offset. Thanks.

Comment: @Giorgio - be sure to take a look at the box-shadow solution as well